# Trying to make a svg-image to show up. Cant find out why it doesn't

Tags: html

I cant figure out, why this svg-graphic doesn't show up.
I know that you may not see anything unless there is a svg in your environment,
but I especially want this to work.
Working in Dreamweaver and the image shows perfectly up there, in the preview.
Thanks for your help!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Unbenanntes Dokument</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="allScreens">
        <div id="backpack" class="screens">
            <p align="center">backpack</p>
        </div>
        <div id="playground" class="screens">
            <h1 align="center">playground</h1>
            <object type="image/svg+xml" id="demo" data="/img/blue_box.svg" width="70%">
            </object>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38986481/10967697 this might help you

Comment: Your page work fine with a svg resource from the web. Does the svg you reference show when entering its url in the browser's address bar ? can you share  the svg file ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it might help

```
<img src="image.svg" alt="This is svg image">
```

When using svg as a background

```
<a href="/" class="logo">
   Logo.svg
</a>

.logo {
   display: block;
   text-indent: -9999px;
   width: 100px;
   height: 82px;
   background: url(kiwi.svg);
   background-size: 100px 82px;
 }
```

BLAZING TIP : Check the path of the svg image it might be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Add some height to your image, and it should work. like this height:100px;